# PHP regular expression to find "email":"email@domain.com" pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a function that will find an email string that is in a specific format. I need to find this specific email string within the larger string. The specific email string I need to find has to be in this format:

"email":"email@domain.com"

I need to find any occurrence of this type of string. Here is my function to find that:

```
 function find_email_schema($str){

      preg_match_all('/["email":"]+[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i', $str, $matches);

      return $matches;

  }
```

However, this function isn't working as expected, it finds other emails in the larger string that aren't in this format:

"email":"email@domain.com"

I only want emails that start with "email":

I know that the pattern I'm passing to preg_match_all isn't correct, but I'm not sure what I need to change to only obtain emails that comply with the above format. What do I need to alter in my regex pattern to get this working?

This is the pattern I'm using:

```
 /["email":"]+[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i
```

Comment: `["email":"]+` should be replaced with `"email":"`

Comment: `[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]` can also be shortened to `[-.\w]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `"email":` part is literal, you don't need to enclose it between `[` `]`, so try this one (I also add the email address enclosing `"` optional with the `?`):

```
 /"email":"?[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+"?/i
```

`[` `]` are used to declare character ranges like `a-z` indicating from `a` to `z`, like you did for the next part.

Let's try it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1fwQyj/1):

[image]